# Convert string array representation back to an array

Tags: javascript

I have a string representation of an array:

```
'["item1", "item2", "item3"]'
```

I'm trying to convert this back to an array.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a [JSON string](http://www.json.org/). Just use the "standard" [JSON script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse('["item1", "item2", "item3"]');`

Answer (score 3):

Try [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings):

```
 ary = JSON.parse(s);
```

Most browsers support it natively, for others you'll need [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: Note that if the string is not valid JSON (for instance if it uses single quotes), this will throw an exception. You *could* also use `eval` for this task and it will accept single quotes, but make sure you think it through first.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse your answer helped me

Answer (score -1):

You also can Use

```
var genericList = eval('(' + s + ')');

for(i=0;i<genericList.lengthl;i++){
   alert("element : " + genericList[i]);
}
```