# Javascript parse jsonarray in jsonarray

Tags: javascript, json

how do I access the crop array in this array from javascript? I may have many ids

```
[{"id":"1","crop":"[{\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":6,\"commonName\":\"Wheat\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}, {\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":5,\"commonName\":\"Sugarcane\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}]]
```

Comment: maybe you need ... arrayName[0].crop

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: If you get this whole response as JSON, then you have a string containing JSON inside JSON, which is very odd. If you are creating this yourself, you should fix the generation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your syntax is wrong, you are missing `"` and `}` at the end

here is corrected code:

```
var data = [{"id":"1","crop":"[{\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":6,\"commonName\":\"Wheat\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}, {\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":5,\"commonName\":\"Sugarcane\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}]"}];
var crop = JSON.parse(data[0].crop);
alert(crop);
```

online version: http://jsfiddle.net/w38Ku/1/

you have to parse "crop" before you can use it as an object, because you have stored it as a string, not json object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `JSON.parse(a["crop"]);`

Also have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003706/convert-string-array-representation-back-to-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var x = [{"id":"1","crop":"[{\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":6,\"commonName\":\"Wheat\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}, {\"class\":\"org.project.Crop\",\"id\":5,\"commonName\":\"Sugarcane\",\"description\":\"N/A\",\"diseases\":[],\"growing\":\"N/A\",\"harvest\":\"N/A\"}]];

var crop = JSON.parse(x[0].crop);
```