# String to array of array or elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Is there any in build function in javascript that let's me convert string "[[16, [8, 2], 4], 2, 80]" to an array of array or int [[16, [8, 2], 4], 2, 80]

Comment: `JSON.pasre("[[16, [8, 2], 4], 2, 80]")`

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: @brk Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003706/convert-string-array-representation-back-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
JSON.parse("[[16, [8, 2], 4], 2, 80]")
```