# How to read the content of a .txt file as an array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, fs

I want to save arrays in `.txt` files and then do a `fs.readFile` to recover them and save them in variables with javascript. Currently my code reads and saves the files as strings.

Example of an array saved in a file:

```
[[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]]
```

My relevant code:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./Arrays/'+array1+'.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(data) // logs the array as a string
console.log(typeof data) // returns string
```

I want

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./Arrays/'+array1+'.txt', 'utf8');
```

to be equivalent to

```
var data =  [[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
    [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
    [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
    [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
    [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],
    [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]];
```

Comment: why not save it as `.json` and then just use require?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I added one minimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it's the right way to do this as it opposes huge risks but you can use `eval(string)` and will convert it to array. You can also try to split it but will require a much bigger effort since it is a 2-dimensional array.

Edit: You can also try with `JSON.parse(string)`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003706/convert-string-array-representation-back-to-an-array)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works as intended! Can you explain why it's risky?

Comment: Because eval() will execute any JS code provided as input, hence it can cause bugs out of nowhere. Check `JSON.parse(string)` cause it's much safer. Please select my answer as correct if I helped you.

Comment: Oh wow thanks again. I dont understand...Before asking the question i used JSON.parse() and it did not work as intended. There was probably another error (maybe i forgot the encoding). It works now.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume `myData.json` contains

```
[[3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,56,76]]
```

then from another file (let's say in the same folder)

```
const myData = require('./myData.json')
// now consume it
console.log(myData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. That's also a good idea however @vmank 's solution was a bit closer to what i was looking for.

Comment: np... I just wondered why not use the `json`  extension instead of `txt` since things are easier.